# What is the gcd of x+1 and x-1?

Tags: gcd-and-lcm

What is the $gcd$ of $x+1$ and $x-1$? The euclid algorithm says that it is 2, but I'm unsure, since if I divide $x+1$ by $x-1$, the remainder is 2.

Comment: Depends on $x$ but since $d=\gcd (x+1,x-1)\implies d \,|,\,x+1-(x-1)=2$ we see that $d$ is either $1$ or $2$.

Comment: Just to give examples:  $x=3\implies d = 2$ and $x=4\implies d=1$.

Comment: Note:  I assumed you meant $x$ to stand for some integer.  If, instead, you meant $x\pm 1$ to denote polynomials then you need to specify what the field or ring of coefficients is.

Answer (score 1):

Rather, the Euclidean algorithm shows in this way that their greatest common divisor is **at most** $2.$ Can you figure out for which $x$ it is equal to $2$ and for which it is equal to $1$?